# print an integer in ada83(Only) Not Ada95

Tags: ada

I am trying to print an integer in Ada83 .All the web sites have the info regarding Ada95 way of printing i.e Integer_Text_IO.Put (C); but this does not get compiled in Ada83. How Do I print an Integer in Ada83(Its a course requirement )?

Answer (score 5):

`Integer_Text_IO` is an instantiation of `Integer_IO`, provided in the standard library in Ada 95.

In Ada 83, the generic package `Integer_IO` exists; you just have to instantiate it yourself.

(You can also use `Integer'Image`, but that adds an annoying leading space for non-negative values.)

(I'm not going to show code because you say it's a school assignment.)

Comment: Code :   with Text_IO ,Integer_IO;
use Text_IO, Integer_IO;                                         After compiling .....                                                gnatmake -gnat83  parser.adb
gcc-4.6 -c -gnat83 parser.adb
parser.adb:1:15: file "integer_io.ads" not found
gnatmake: "parser.adb" compilation error    Kinldy help with this

Comment: @user3422455: `Integer_IO` is not a library unit, so you can't refer to it in a `with` clause. It's a generic package declared inside `Text_IO`.

Comment: I am on project ---deadline is in 2 days ..I have been stuck with this simple reason Kindly provide the code.I tried many ways but not working out.

Comment: `Integer_IO` is a generic package declared inside `Text_IO`. You need to create an instance of `Text_IO.Integer_IO` with the predefined type `Integer` as a parameter. Then you need to call the `Put` function, defined in your instance, with an `Integer` value as its argument. (If you don't want leading spaces, you'll need to add `, Width => 0` to the call.) Which of these steps are you having trouble with?

Comment: I am Extremely new to Ada Working on this from past 10 days.. I was able to solve everything through the code sample available on the internet.. For this i am unable to find so .I dont have any idea about Packages or any conceptual stuff in Ada.. Could you do a favour by posting a small bit of code .. Thanks in advance