# How to print integers in ada83 environment

Tags: ada

I want to print integers in Ada 83. At present I am just using 'with Text_IO' and 'use Text_IO'. I don't want to print using the Integer'Image option. I want to use Integer_Text_IO in ada83. Please help me out with the syntax.

I am using below code:

```
 with Text_IO;
 use Text_IO;
 i: INTEGER :=1; 
 package Int_IO is new Integer_IO(INTEGER);
 use Int_IO; put(i);
```

I am getting 'expect signed integer type in instantiation of "Num" ' error.

Comment: have you tried anything so far? please provide some code samples.

Comment: with Text_IO; use Text_IO; i: INTEGER :=1; package Int_IO is new Integer_IO(INTEGER); use Int_IO; put(i); I am getting 'expect signed integer type in instantiation of "Num" ' error.

Comment: I'm assuming there's some additional lines in there somewhere, such as a `procedure` or `function` declaration, and a `begin`?  Assuming there is, and that you've put the above statements in the correct places, it should work fine, unless you've done something like redefining INTEGER.

Comment: possible duplicate of [print an integer in ada83(Only) Not Ada95](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23257846/print-an-integer-in-ada83only-not-ada95)

Answer (score 1):

The example below, which compiles, should help.

But please, when posting a question on StackOverflow (or anywhere on the Net, really) show us the code you’ve actually tried. The sample you’ve provided doesn’t come close to compiling (it fails at line 3 with `compilation unit expected`), and that makes it very hard for us to work out how to help you.

You’ll get `expect signed integer type in instantiation of “Num”` if you try to instantiate `Text_IO` with the wrong sort of type (for example, `Float`).

```
with Text_IO;
procedure Integer_IO_Demo is
   package Int_IO is new Text_IO.Integer_IO (Integer);
begin
   for J in 5 .. 10 loop
      Int_IO.Put (J);
      Text_IO.New_Line;
   end loop;
end Integer_IO_Demo;
```